# permission PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(int)

Tags: java, android, permissions, package

I've a question about this method : PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(int) 
how to know which permissions i need to use this method ?

i've found this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)

but i don't find where to know permissions i need...

some help please ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can remember you don't need any special permissions for that. You can just call it without any permissions.
I tested that and it is working fine without any permissions on my device.

Comment: ok thanks, because it's a question for an exercice at school, and we ask me the permission for this method, and i found nothing so maybe there is no permission as you say